# JITO Scam and increased allowance

Tags: metamask, scam

Forgive me, I am really green, but went to this site and connected my wallet

https://jito-airdrop.pages.dev/

Now my avax and luna are gone, and its listed as

Increase Allowance
Status
Confirmed
View on block explorer
Copy transaction ID
From 0x1c1e3...5Bb3F
To
LUNA Token

has this been stolen from me, or how to i claw back this transaction?